# What is the correct way of passing parameters to stats.friedmanchisquare based on a DataFrame?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I am trying to pass values to [stats.friedmanchisquare](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.friedmanchisquare.html#scipy.stats.friedmanchisquare) from a dataframe `df`, that has shape `(11,17)`.

This is what **works** for me (only for three rows in this example):

```
df = df.as_matrix()
print stats.friedmanchisquare(df[1, :], df[2, :], df[3, :])
```

which yields

```
(16.714285714285694, 0.00023471398805908193)
```

However, the line of code is too long when I want to use all `11` rows of  `df`.

**First**, I tried to pass the values in the following manner:

```
df = df.as_matrix()
print stats.friedmanchisquare([df[x, :] for x in np.arange(df.shape[0])])
```

but I get:

```
ValueError: 
Less than 3 levels.  Friedman test not appropriate.
```

**Second**, I also tried not converting it to a matrix-form leaving it as a DataFrame (which would be ideal for me), but I guess this is not supported yet, or I am doing it wrong:

```
print stats.friedmanchisquare([row for index, row in df.iterrows()])
```

which also gives me the error:

```
ValueError: 
Less than 3 levels.  Friedman test not appropriate.
```

So, my question is: what is the correct way of passing parameters to [stats.friedmanchisquare](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.friedmanchisquare.html#scipy.stats.friedmanchisquare) based on `df`? (or even using its `df.as_matrix()` representation)

You can download my dataframe in csv format [here](http://reev.us/ys/df.csv) and read it using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
```

Thank you for your help :)

### Solution:

Based on @Ami Tavory and @vicg's answers (please vote on them), the solution to my problem, based on the matrix representation of the data, is to add the `*`-operator [defined here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), but [better explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/4992019), as follows:

```
df = df.as_matrix()
print stats.friedmanchisquare(*[df[x, :] for x in np.arange(df.shape[0])])
```

And the same is true if you want to work with the original dataframe, which is what I ideally wanted:

```
print stats.friedmanchisquare(*[row for index, row in df.iterrows()])
```

in this manner you iterate over the dataframe in its native format.

**Note** that I went ahead and ran some `timeit` tests to see which way is faster and as it turns out, converting it first to a `numpy array` beforehand is **twice as fast** than using `df` in its original dataframe format.

This was my experimental setup:

```
import timeit

setup = '''
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
'''

theCommand = '''
df = np.array(df)
stats.friedmanchisquare(*[df[x, :] for x in np.arange(df.shape[0])])
'''

print min(timeit.Timer(stmt=theCommand, setup=setup).repeat(10, 10000))

theCommand = '''
stats.friedmanchisquare(*[row for index, row in df.iterrows()])
'''

print min(timeit.Timer(stmt=theCommand, setup=setup).repeat(10, 10000))
```

which yields the following results:

```
4.97029900551
8.7627799511
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass it using the ["star operator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python), similarly to this:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4] ,[4, 5, 6]])
friedmanchisquare(*(a[i, :] for i in range(a.shape[0])))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see with your first attempt is that you end up passing one list with multiple dataframes inside of it.

The stats.friedmanchisquare needs multiple array_like arguments, not one list

Try using the [* (star/unpack)](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) operator to unpack the list

Like this

```
df = df.as_matrix()
print stats.friedmanchisquare(*[df[x, :] for x in np.arange(df.shape[0])])
```